# How can I tokenize numbers from multiple locales with Java's breakIterator?

Tags: java, parsing, text, locale, multilingual

I want Java's breakIterator to treat both ,123 and .123 as the decimal number 123/1000 (i.e. accept both . and , as a decimal point), accept both . and , as thousands separators, etc. Can this be done? If not, is there some other (simple) Java library with this functionality?

**Note:** This is not about the parsing of values, just the tokenization. 123,456 might mean a different number in different locales, I just don't want it to be interpreted as two numbers.

Comment: How would you tell is 123,456 is 123456 or 123.456?

Comment: @JBNizet: Oh, I wasn't clear enough. These are all numbers, I don't care about their value.

Comment: Now it's even more obscure. What would be the signature and javadoc of the method you want to implement?

Comment: @JBNizet: Same as for breakIterator, I just want it to treat both 1,2 and 1.2 as single words and not break in the middle of them.